# Tab View Controller Window Sizing Stuck

Tags: xcode, macos, nstabview, nstabviewcontroller

Whenever I implement a Tab View Controller the window sizing seems to be stuck in the same configuration, even when I change all the window and view controller sizing values.
[image: For example, all of these are 300x100]
[image: But this is always what is shown]

Answer (score 0):

The issue will go away after you add subviews and constraints to the view.

Comment: In the "Add New Constraints" popup, all of the constraints options are grayed out. "Constrain to margins" isn't, but it does nothing when I toggle it.

Comment: Did you add any subviews?